# ggplot2 bar chart sign on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following data :

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c("UK1", "UK2", "UK3", "UK4", "UK5", "UK6", "UK7"), 
                     n = c(50, 55, 58, 64, 14, 18, 45), 
                     F = c(-6, 17, 26, -37, 44, -22, 15), 
                     z = c("a", "a", "b", "a" , "b", "b", "a"))
```

I want to create a ggplot (bar chart) of column x (x axis) against column n (y-axis) colour split by column z. The tricky part is I want to bar chart to be going up the way if the value in F is positive and down the way if negative. Is this possible with ggplot?

Comment: You're getting a thumbs up for providing a data frame. But your question refers to both `z` and `Z`; the latter should be `F` to correspond to that in the data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution using [`sign`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/sign):**

You can use `sign()` to extract sign of `F` and multiply that by `n`: `n * sign(F)`

```
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- data.frame(x = c("UK1", "UK2", "UK3", "UK4", "UK5", "UK6", "UK7"), 
                     n = c(50, 55, 58, 64, 14, 18, 45), 
                     F = c(-6, 17, 26, -37, 44, -22, 15), 
                     z = c("a", "a", "b", "a" , "b", "b", "a"))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x, n * sign(F), fill = z)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My rep is too low to comment or upvote, so here an answer that builds upon the previous one:

```
  ggplot(mydata) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = x, y =(n*ifelse(F<0,-1,1)), fill = z), stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=abs)
```

This adds the direction in 1 go (no need for an extra column), and transforms the labels of the y axis with the `abs()` function.

Comment: Good tip using `labels = abs`

Answer (score 1):

A barchart in ggplot2 is made with `geom_bar`, but this defaults to using the `stat_bin`, i.e. it counts occurrences in bins for you. The trick is to tell ggplot2 to use the values as is. This is done with `geom_bar(stat='identity')`.

Secondly, to have some go up and some go down, you need the value of the variable to be, well, positive and negative. I've made one approach in the code below.

```
mydata$dir <- ifelse(mydata$F < 0, -1, 1)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x, y=n*dir, colour=z)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to overwrite the x axis to make the values absolute. So the axis would go from 60 to 30 to 0 to 30 to 60

Comment: Take a look at `scale_y_continuous`; you'll have to set both `breaks` and `labels` manually.